# Universal link with randomly generated token with branch.io

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I have created a deep link successfully & configured baranch.io, but the problem is I have a URL e.g: https://example.com/magiclink/token/*

so, if you can see above the URL, there is * at the end, which means after the "token/" the unique token will be shared instead of *, so as you know in branch.io as far as I know, it gives us the static link to be shared with someone. but in my case, the link can not be static.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to pass a unique token with each of your links then you can append it to your Branch.io link as a Link parameter.

eg. https://www.example.com/magiclink?token=*

Now, you can dynamically change the value of the token and it won't affect your link.